# Compiling kernel gives error No rule to make target 'debian/certs/debian-uefi-certs.pem'

Tags: linux, makefile, compiler-errors, kernel

Compiling kernel gives error `No rule to make target 'debian/certs/debian-uefi-certs.pem`
I am following this tutorial https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

```
CC      kernel/jump_label.o
CC      kernel/iomem.o
CC      kernel/rseq.o
AR      kernel/built-in.a
CC      certs/system_keyring.o
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/certs/debian-uefi-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1851: certs] Error 2
```

Comment: This thread might help you :  ``lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2016/04/msg00579.html``. In the .config file copied from /boot find and comment out the lines CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEY and CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY.

Comment: @Altaf let me check

Comment: sure let me know if it works

Comment: @user786: Use **code** formatting for output. That way you could achieve needed representations without adding newlines manually.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok thanks keep in mind next time I ask question

Comment: @Altaf its installed `uname -r` outputs `5.12.6` 

Note I mistakenly typed `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.6.9` 
instead of sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.12.6 but I typed again for `5.12.6` it worked

Comment: @user786 good to know that

Comment: @Altaf I need to compile again. How can I set debug flag inside make file or do I need to pass it with `make` command in terminal something like `make DEBUG_FLAG 1`. Are u familiar with this?

Comment: @user786 As far as i know any macros can be given using the ```-D``` switch. These macros are then used in the source code.Example: If you want to do inside a makefile, then : ```CFLAGS +=-DDEBUG_FLAG=1```.In makefile you can: ```ifeq ($(DEBUG_FLAG), 1)
    CFLAGS +=-DDEBUG_FLAG=1
endif

.o: .c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)``` and then use : ``make DEBUG_FLAG=1``

Comment: @Altaf ok I will check

Comment: Below answer helped me...changing parameter value in .config file
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329538/compiling-the-kernel-5-11-11

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to be the way to go with the current version:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/649484/301245

There are many, many config flags now, and the signing system must stay operational for the build to work. Easiest is to copy debian/ and debian.master/ into the source tree of the kernel to be built, then it works without additional changes.
Well, almost: It can happen that references to key files still exist. The keys section in the .conf file should look like this:

```
#
# Certificates for signature checking
#
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="certs/signing_key.pem"
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_SECONDARY_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_HASH_LIST=""
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_LIST=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS=""
# end of Certificates for signature checking
```

Comment: I fixed it some time ago. Probably need to compile kernel again soon for this. Can u please take a look if u can https://superuser.com/questions/1671204/iptables-use-to-ignore-tcp-packets-not-reject-but-ignoring-including-syc-comnin

Answer (score 22):

Instead of removing the kernel signature checking, I've just configured it correctly:

```ini
#
# Certificates for signature checking
#
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="certs/signing_key.pem"
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY_TYPE_RSA=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY_TYPE_ECDSA=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="/usr/local/src/debian/canonical-certs.pem"
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_SECONDARY_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_HASH_LIST=""
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_LIST=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS="/usr/local/src/debian/canonical-revoked-certs.pem"
# end of Certificates for signature checking
```

To get there, I've just followed these steps:

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/src/debian
sudo apt install linux-source
sudo cp -v /usr/src/linux-source-*/debian/canonical-*.pem /usr/local/src/debian/
sudo apt purge linux-source*
```

...which:

1. installs the Ubuntu Linux kernel sources
2. copies the certificates into a dedicated non-package-managed directory
3. removes any kernel sources package again

This process can be repeated whenever an update is required (e.g. new certificates).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you need the **Ubuntu** `linux-source` package. A standard Debian `linux-source` does not have Ubuntu signing keys.

Answer (score 6):

If you get the certificate error, execute the following in the root of the kernel source

```
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS
```

Then run `make` again and it should work!

Comment: please explain the logic behind your answer

Comment: I tried this, and it worked. looks like the key is getting regenerated,  
Generating a RSA private key
................................................................................................................++++
...................................................................++++
writing new private key to 'certs/signing_key.pem'
-----

Answer (score 2):

Run `ln -s /usr/src/linux-source-x.y.z/debian debian` in the top level directory of the kernel source tree. Replace `x.y.z` with the appropriate kernel version.

Comment: I upvoted it, but I didn't try it. So please don't interpret my upvote as "this works" so much as "why didn't anybody think of that ?!?!?"

Answer (score 2):

Execute this:

```bash
sudo apt install linux-buildinfo-$(uname -r)
```

Then open the *.config* file in a text editor and change:

```
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS="debian/canonical-revoked-certs.pem"
```

to

```
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS="/usr/lib/linux/$(uname -r)/canonical-certs.pem"
```

Then try to compile it again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you provided, it seems that your Linux kernel configuration file contains similar paths as shown below:

```
#
# Certificates for signature checking
#
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="certs/signing_key.pem"
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY_TYPE_RSA=y
# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY_TYPE_ECDSA is not set
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="debian/canonical-certs.pem"
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_SECONDARY_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_HASH_LIST=""
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_LIST=y
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS="debian/canonical-revoked-certs.pem"
# end of Certificates for signature checking
```

To resolve this issue, you can follow the steps below:

1. Create a directory named debian/certs in the Linux build root directory.
2. Copy the certificates from the current kernel to the newly created debian/certs directory.

```
sudo cp -v /usr/src/$(uname -r)/debian/certs/* /path-to-linux-Build/debian/certs/
```

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, How can you be so sure that this response is generated by an AI system?

Comment: I encountered this issue during the compilation of kernel version 5.15.26

Comment: Well, to be clear, I didn't say that I was "sure."  I said that it "appears likely" and recommend that you delete it *if* that's the case.  My observation is based on my experience with (literally) several thousand AI answers here on Stack Overflow.  I don't doubt that you experienced this issue yourself since you are posting on this question 2 years later and aren't posting *mass* answers (as some people do).  For clarity, however, are you saying that you *didn't* use any form of AI to come up with the solution?

Comment: Also, I fully support the [responsible use of AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710) here on Stack Overflow.  Part of this includes validating the answer, which I do believe you have done.  However, for now AI is banned outright, as far too many people aren't using it responsibly.

Comment: I might have utilized grammarly to rephrase my answer (added as a plugin in my apps like Word, Gmail, etc.) and I did not rely on an AI tool for this specific task.

Comment: Ok, just be careful with that [green light bulb](https://www.grammarly.com/grammarlygo) in Grammarly since it appears to now generate text via GPT as well.