# Recovering ko files accidentally removed

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, kernel-module

I accidentally removed these files:

```
removed '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-41-generic/include/config/HID_REDRAGON'
removed '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic/include/config/HID_REDRAGON'
removed '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic/include/config/HID_REDRAGON'
removed '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic/include/config/HID_REDRAGON'
removed '/usr/lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-redragon.ko'
removed '/usr/lib/modules/5.19.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-redragon.ko'
```

I was able to restore files that was located under '/usr/src/' by reinstalling header files:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.19.0-41-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic
```

I am not able to recompile ***.ko** files, can someone please guide me to accomplish this ?

Comment: Build the kernel (`make` from `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-41-generic` directory), then build modules (`make modules`) and install them (`make modules_install`). There are a lot information about building Linux kernel and its modules.

Comment: If you do a `dpkg -S /usr/lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-redragon.ko`, does it tell you which dpkg it came from?

Comment: @Tsyvarev executing `make modules` is getting me `make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.`.

Comment: @AndyJ executing command you suggest is getting me `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-redragon.ko`.

Comment: The error about `debian/canonical-certs.pem` is easily googled. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67670169/compiling-kernel-gives-error-no-rule-to-make-target-debian-certs-debian-uefi-ce).

Comment: I solved error about `debian/canonical-certs.pem` but when I try to build the kernel from `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-41-generic` directory I get this `make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.`. I tied googled for this but I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Can't you just do a `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-5.19.0-41-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic`?

Comment: The linux-modules packages install module files to `/lib/modules`, not `/usr/lib/modules`. `dpkg-query -S` needs the correct installation path even though `/lib` is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved by running these two commands:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-41-generic
```