# Issues encountered when deploying AMD SEV on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu

I followed the solution under that question[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67670169/compiling-kernel-gives-error-no-rule-to-make-target-debian-certs-debian-uefi-ce), but the following error still occurred.

```
make[7]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:480: certs] Error 2
make[6]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  UPD     init/utsversion-tmp.h
  CC      init/version.o
  AR      init/built-in.a
  CHK     kernel/kheaders_data.tar.xz
make[5]: *** [Makefile:1913: .] Error 2
make[4]: *** [Makefile:359: __build_one_by_one] Error 2
make[3]: *** [debian/rules:25: build-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: make -f debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:146: bindeb-pkg] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/home/epyc/AMDSEV/distros/ubuntu-18.04/src/linux/Makefile:1538: bindeb-pkg] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
ERROR: make -j 16 bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-sev
```